# node JSON https request becoming undefined

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, httprequest

I am trying to send a single https request to an API, with a bunch of data in JSON format.

However, when running the code, I first ran into the problem that everything was undefined. I commented out my loop, trying to parse the data I needed, and right now I'm just trying to console.log all of the data.

However, it seems to still be looping through stuff somehow despite not having a loop anywhere in my code anymore.

here is the code for my request:

```
function getCards() {
  // make a request
  var options = {
    host: 'omgvamp-hearthstone-v1.p.mashape.com',
    path: '/cards',
    method: 'GET',
  };

  var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log('STATUS ' + res.statusCode);
    console.log('HEADERS ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function(data) {
      //console.log(data);
      updateCardsCollection(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
  });

  req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
  });

  req.end();
}
```

The weird thing is that the console.log(data) in the above code, logs out all of the data just fine.

```
function updateCardsCollection(data) {
  var cardsRaw = [];
  console.log("DATA");
  console.log("===========================================================");
  console.log(data.Classic);
}
```

Here "Classic" is one of the arrays of objects in the API.

Before implementing node, express, mongoose and jade. The following loop worked fine to parse through the data:

```
   for(var key in data) {
     for(var i = 0; i < data[key].length; i++) {
       console.log(data[key][i].cardId);
```

However the above beginning of a loop would print out an undefined error as well.

Another strange problem I seem to be having with this code is when I run it with the loop commented out, with just the 3 console.logs in the 'updateCardsCollection' function. It logs those 3 lines a lot of times. Despite the function only being called once.

Any idea why this code is no longer working for getting my API data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first, you need to do `JSON.parse` instead of `JSON.stringify`  while you try to update your collection, if you want work with objects, not with string.

But if you done with first, your code still not work, because in `data` handler you get `chunked` data, not full response. See https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback for it.

You must accumulate data like this:

```
const req = https.request(options, res => {
    const data = [];
    res.on('data', d => data.push(d));
    res.on('end', () => updateCardsCollection(JSON.parse(data.join(''))));
})
```

Comment: This worked great! thank you.

If anyone else stumbles upon this question. The above code has 2 missing parenthesis' there should be 4 after data.join(''))))* and one after the last curly brace. Other than that it works perfectly!

Comment: I am trying to perform DELETE request and getting error `Unexpected end of JSON input`  in  `res.on('end'...`